# Long delays when formatting a .cshtml file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Working with MVC4 using Visual Studio 2012 at the moment and when every I format a CSHTML document (CTRL + E + D) I get the "Waiting for a background operation to complete dialog"

This dialog stays around for roughly a minutes however I've had wait times of up to 10minutes before.

My document is not long it consists of 20< lines of basic html.

I'm only using 1 Add-in; Visual Git.

EDIT: Removing the Add-in has no effect.

EDIT2: I'm now getting the following error trying to edit the file after trying to format.

```
 Attempted TextBuffer edit operation while another edit is in progress.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it seemed to be related with the razor syntax, since I only had it on one particular file.

For example if I put the following code in one line I had the described issue.

```
@section BodyClassName {note}
```

But when putting the closing parenthesis on the next line the issue went away

```
@section BodyClassName {note
    }
```

Kind regards

Stijn

Comment: A space either side fixes it as well: @section BodyClassName { note }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i did the following and it worked for me.

1. UnCheck the ReadOnly attribute of your View(By using windows explorer)
2. If you already have your view open in VS, then close your view and open it again.
3. If you can click on Refresh button at the top of Solution Explorer, that will also reload the files.

It should be editable.

I hope that will help.

Thanks.